# Charts in excel sheet getting a message invalid references

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have data in 2 fields where we have fields with status in one column and month in another column.

I wrote a macro to create a report monthly wise to get the counts and quarterly report with counts in another worksheet in same workbook.

Macro is working fine in generating the report monthly and quarterly. Now I thought of automating the graphs using the same.

I created charts using the data and positioned them in another sheet on same book referencing the output generated from macro.

But when I run the macro again the graphs are not being refreshed and I am getting invalid references error.

Answer (score 2):

Some more information might be needed but to answer your question:

"the graphs are not being refreshed":
put this at the end of your macro; `Workbook.RefreshAll`

"getting invalid references error":
If your macro is deleting cells, this will be causing the issue, check to see if your using `.delete` and replace with `.clear` / alternatively look at using named ranges for your graphs; once you've created your output change the named range using `Range("'chart range'").Name = "Chart"`

Comment: Thanks alot,clear did helped me..Here in my case now i already fixed the charts on the other sheet..Is there any way where we can generate the charts automatically for the 3 tables data that is generated automatically via macro..

Comment: yes you can, I personally don't like to generate charts via VBA as I find altering the charts aesthetics difficult when refreshing the data usually does the job. If you are re-creating charts (duplicating existing ones) that could be easier. But to make one you follow the below:

`Set co = Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(50, 40, 200, 100) 
co.Chart.ChartWizard Source:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("chart range"), _ 
 Gallery:=xlColumn, Format:=6, PlotBy:=xlColumns, _ 
 CategoryLabels:=1, SeriesLabels:=0, HasLegend:=1`